# Q: create a vc from sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:) cannot use its property in swift

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, type-conversion

Create a `vc10` from `sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:)`,can not use its `property` even convert its type to `ViewController10`.

this below is my code:

`vc9:`

```
let sb = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
var vc10 = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController10")

//vc10.delegate = self // there is the error: Value of type 'UIViewController' hs no member 'delegate'
(ViewController10(vc10)).delegate = self // this did not work too 

self.navigationController!.pushViewController(vc10, animated: true)
```

`vc10:`

```
var delegate:ViewController9?  // this is the property delegate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert it to `ViewController10` when you init it like:

```
var vc10 = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController10") as! ViewController10
```